# Set image contrast -- swift

Tags: swift, xcode, image

I want to set up a function in swift that will set the contrast of an image to full/max.

```
func contrastImage(in image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    let outpic = image
    return outpic
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make this happen.
Hopefully someone can help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Core Image's [CIFilter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorControls):

```
func increaseContrast(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: image)!
    let parameters = [
        "inputContrast": NSNumber(value: 2)
    ]
    let outputImage = inputImage.applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: parameters)

    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let img = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent)!
    return UIImage(cgImage: img)
}
```

Adjust `inputContrast` as you please: a value of 1 means no changes. Less than 1 mean desaturate. Greater than 1 means increasing the contrast.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly, quick question tho, is 2 the max contrast? And 0 the minimum contrast? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: what are the min & max values for contrast ?